# Is the cuspidal cubic $\{y^2 = x^3\} \subset \Bbb R^2$ not smooth?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, singularity

Cuspidal cubic $y^2=x^3$ in $\Bbb R^2$ "seems to be not smooth" intuitively because its pictured graph has a cusp at the origin. But I read from book that it is a smooth manifold. I feel so confused. How do we understand "smooth"?

Furthermore, it is not a regular submanifold of $\Bbb R^2$. I don't know how to prove this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You probably mean the $y$-axis?

Comment: Yes, I mean the projection onto the $y$-axis is a homeomorphism. Damn signs had me confused.

Answer (score 10):

The cuspidal cubic $C := \{(x, y) : y^2 = x^3\} \subset \Bbb R^2$ certainly admits a smooth structure: The projection $C \to \Bbb R$ onto the $y$-axis is continuous and has continuous inverse $y \mapsto (y^{2 / 3}, y)$, so it is a homeomorphism, and hence using it to pull back the (usual) smooth structure on $\Bbb R$ defines a smooth structure on $C$.

Like you say, however, $C$ is *not* an embedded (regular) submanifold of $\Bbb R^2$: the pullback by inclusion $C \hookrightarrow \Bbb R^2$ does *not* define a smooth structure on $C$: If we regard tangent vectors as equivalence classes of differentiable curves into $C$, we can observe that any differentiable curve $\gamma: (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to C$ such that $\gamma(0) = (0, 0)$ must satisfy $\gamma'(0) = (0, 0)$.

Comment: For those interested, Do Carmo has a nice treatment of this material.