# Spivak Calculus on Manifolds - Definition of a k-dimensional manifold

Tags: general-topology, analysis, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

[image]
Above is one of the two definitions of a k-dimensional manifold in Spivak Calculus on Manifolds.

Could someone explain to me why $f'(y)$ must have rank k?

Thank you.

Comment: By the way, that book is an oldie but a goodie, so great choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With apologies, this is really more of a motivation than a definition, but the way I like to think about it is this: you want a smooth manifold to have enough of the properties of $\mathbb{R}^k$ so that you can generalize notions from calculus or analysis to them. One thing that smooth functions in $\mathbb{R}^k$ have that you might want is the Jacobian, which is telling you something about how your function is varying in different directions at a point.

Requiring $f'$ to have rank $k$ at all points in the manifold is exactly what will allow you to export this property to the more general setting of manifolds. We don't want rank less than $k$, because then at that point we lose some information about functions defined on our manifold, and we don't want rank *greater* than $k$ because you're hoping for something with only $k$ dimensions.

Ahhh, in response to your clarification, let's reason it out: $f$, in the proof, is a function $W \subset \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^n$, and $H$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^k$. The idea is that because the composition of functions is the identity (at least on this subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$), its Jacobian must also be the identity $k\times k$ matrix. But when is this possible? Only when $f'$ is one-to-one as a linear transformation, i.e. when its matrix has rank $k$.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But as I wrote down in the another comment above, I am sorry that my question was actually not what I intended to ask. Could you explain why, in the proof, the author says $f'(y)$ must have rank $k$ as $H'(f(y)) \cdot f'(y) = I$? I tried to use the fact that rank $AB$ $\leq$ min (rank $A$ , rank $B$) but failed.

Comment: I made edits, I hope they're helpful

Comment: Thank you!! I think now I understand, so I upvoted your answer. I would greatly appreciate it if you check if I understand correctly. 
My understanding of your explanation is that because the Jacobian matrix of the composition of the two functions is also the $k \times k$identity, $f'$ should have at least rank k. But because $f'$ can have at most rank k as it is a $n \times k$ matrix, $f'$ has rank k and is 1-1.

Comment: yes! that's correct!

Answer (score 2):

The really simple version is that you are going (forgetting about manifolds) $\mathbb{R}^k\to \mathbb{R}^n$, so that is a $n\times k$ matrix.  But if the derivative (which says how much "like a $k$-plane" the function is) doesn't have the right rank, then you could possibly lose a dimension even though the function itself is 1-1.

For instance, take the function $f(t)=(t^2,t^3)$ from the reals to $\mathbb{R}^2$.  An open set around zero is certainly going on a one-to-one basis to the curve $y^2=x^3$ here, and the derivative exists everywhere $(2t,3t^2)$.  (I guess the inverse is continuous too, though I'm too lazy to check that now.)

But the derivative does NOT have rank $k=1$ at $t=0$, it's the zero matrix.  And indeed the image isn't a manifold, it has a singularity/cusp.

[image]

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231892/showing-something-isnt-a-manifold) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1760794/is-the-cuspidal-cubic-y2-x3-subset-bbb-r2-not-smooth) for probably a better answer.  Also, there are topological manifolds, which if I recall correctly only require continuity.  Hope I got this all right.

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation! But I am sorry that my question was actually not what I intended to ask. Could you explain why, in the proof, the author says $f'(y)$ must have rank $k$ as $H'(f(y)) \cdot f'(y) = I$? I tried to use the fact that rank $AB$ $\leq$ min (rank $A$ , rank $B$) but failed.

Comment: Looks like you got the explanation above - great!  Sorry I couldn't be of more timely assistance.